# Check if tuple is in multiple columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4], 'col2' : ['one','two','three','four'], 'col3': ['abc','xyz','pqr','rst']})
df
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       one     abc
1   2       two     xyz
2   3       three   pqr
3   4       four    rst
```

How can we search if a multiple values across different columns ?

```
value_to_search = (1,'one')
```

In above case, we want to search for `1` in `col1` and `one` in col2.

One way would be to

```
df[ (df['col1']==value_to_search[0]) & (df['col2']==value_to_search[1])]
```

- But the above method is not clean when you have to search large number of values. (eg : `values_to_search = (1,'one','uno','first','abc'...)`)

Another way could be to iterate over rows but that would be inefficient way.

Is there any clean efficient way ?

Comment: Whats your exact goal? To see if each tuple is in the same row? or if the values are in the df at all?

Comment: Primary to see if that tuple is present in the dataframe. If yes, return that row.

Comment: it would be helpful if you created an expected output.

Comment: How would you handle `values_to_search = (1,'one','uno','first','abc'...)`, how can you tell which values have to be searched for in each column?

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer provided by @abc, one cleaner way could be,

```
cols_to_search = ['col1','col2']
df[df[cols_to_search].isin(value_to_search).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I not sure the clean that you mean but you could try the .isin() method.

For example,

```
    options = (1,2,"one",3)

    df.loc[(df["col1"].isin(options)) & (df["col2"]=='one')]

    col1    col2    col3
  0  1      one     abc
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks but in above case, the row `2,one,mno` would also be returned which we do not need.